# How do you preserve permissions from a windows SMB share?

Tags: network, mojave, permission, sharing, smb

I'm troubleshooting an issue where permissions get stripped from folders/files when accessing a Windows SMB share from OSX.

ENV:

OSX Workstations (Mojave)
Windows AD Server (2012 R2)
Windows FTP Server (2012 R2)
Linux Fileserver w/ ZFS (Debian)

Connect to SMB share via AD User.

The issue we're having is moving files from the Windows FTP to the Linux Fileserver with OSX Finder.  When this is attempted all file permissions are stripped and the folder comes out with the current OSX User having full permissions and the everyone group set to No Access.  All other groups are not retained.

- When I push directly from the FTP to the server permissions are good.
- When I check the FTP Folder permissions (Get Info) from OSX they seem correct. "custom" but the groups are right.

I have full access and permission when manipulating folders/files on the FTP Server

Any ideas?